# Uncaught TypeError while sorting JSON using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written the following code to sort a list of items fetched from a JSON array according to different criteria. However, when I click on one of the criteria to sort the list, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLTableSectionElement> has no method 'sort'` in the console. I also get another error, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rollno' of null`. What could be the cause of this problem?

Here is my main script:

```
$(function () {
    jQuery.noConflict();

    $.getJSON('results_new.json', function (data) {
        results = data.results.map(function (raw) {
            return {
                rollno: raw.rollno,
                name: raw.name,
                air: raw.air
            }
        });
    })

    $('#headings th').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var asc = (!$(this).attr('asc'));

        $('#headings th').each(function () {
            $(this).removeAttr('asc');
        });
        if (asc) $(this).attr('asc', 'asc');

        sortResults(id, asc);
    });

    showResults();
});

function sortResults(prop, asc) {
    results = results.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (asc) return (a[prop] > b[prop]);
        else return (b[prop] > a[prop]);
    });
    showResults();
}

function showResults() {
    var html = '';
    for (var e in results) {
        html += '<tr>' + '<td>' + results[e].rollno + '</td>' + '<td>' + results[e].name + '</td>' + '<td>' + results[e].air + '</td>' + '</tr>';
    }
    $('#results').html(html);
}
```

The HTML consists of the headings as `theads` with IDs set to `rollno`, `name` and `air` and an auto-generated `tbody` with ID `results`, which is blank.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: ^^ actually it's not really a duplicate as long the user doesn't click the table headings before the asynchronous ajax call has completed, which seems like a bad design flaw, but at the same it is, as the sorting also happens on pageload, before the results are populated, so really it is ?

Comment: There could be many issues with the presented code including: 1. What does the `result_new.json` structure look like? 2. What scope does the `results` variable reside in? (eg: `document`, `function`, etc.) 3. What have you tried/tested/debugged?

Comment: The `results` variable formats the raw json into a form that is simpler to work with. It is a global variable. The JSON is of the format `{"results":[{"rollno":"123\r","name":" Anony Mouse","air":"1"}]}`. I added `jQuery.noConflict()`, but that does not solve the problem.